# Simple way to delete a file and all its links (simultaneously)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, symbolic-link

I found a lot of questions on how to delete symlinks only, or delete symlinks based on their contents, but no one has asked how to do what I want to do.

Take the following example

```
file-l -> ../file
file-l2 -> ../file
```

I want to delete `file`, `file-l`, and `file-l2` in one fell swoop, without knowing the locations of the other files, preferably by specifying `file` as an argument. (imagine that I have 100+ links to the same file in random places all over the filesystem). Primarily, I would prefer a shell script or built-in program, but external programs are also okay.

After `unlink` and `rm` failed to provide the desired functionality, I initially had the idea to use `inodes` or `stat` or something, but...

```
$ stat test
  File: ‘test’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 27001032    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  braden)   Gid: ( 1000/  braden)
Access: 2015-08-30 21:30:35.578786598 -0600
Modify: 2015-08-30 21:30:35.578786598 -0600
Change: 2015-08-30 21:30:35.578786598 -0600
 Birth: -
$ stat test-l
  File: ‘test-l’ -> ‘test’
  Size: 4           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 27001033    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/  braden)   Gid: ( 1000/  braden)
Access: 2015-08-30 21:30:42.074786598 -0600
Modify: 2015-08-30 21:30:41.426786598 -0600
Change: 2015-08-30 21:30:41.426786598 -0600
 Birth: -
```

Not only does the symlink have a unique inode (that's a given) but there doesn't seem to be any information aside from the file name that I could use to conclude that "yes, this is a symlink to the file I want". If I use the filename, though, then I have to deal with regex-hell. This is something I would personally like to avoid since, in practice, the file names contain characters like space, meta-characters (`?![]{}.,`), and unicode characters.

I would also like to avoid things like awk, perl, crazy hacks that exploit bugs/design-flaws in bash 4.2.XX, and other weird stuff that probably wouldn't work properly (if at all) on a fresh install of, e.g, Arch Linux or CentOS. I should basically be able to run said command/script out-of-the-box on a system that lacks awk, sed, perl, ruby, and python, and runs bash-4.1 as its shell.

If that isn't possible, then I would at least prefer the script/command use/be ubiquitous, like `vi`, `cat`, `ls`, etc.

The bare minimum of my requirements is that the solution:

- can delete a file and all of its symlinks with only the original file as an argument
- can do so without knowing the names or locations of said symlinks
- can do so on symlinks of varying names and varying locations
- works in a fresh, minimal install of Arch Linux (or similar minimal system)
- is not a code-golf
- regexes reasonable and easy-to-understand

This is how I try to design my own scripts, so I consider it reasonable. But I nonetheless hope it isn't too demanding.

Thanks.

---

Edit: I feel like I'm obligated to show my work. Just requesting a script makes me feel like a jerk. So, this is what I have:

```
get_lnk(){
    gl_file="$1"
    gl_orig_a=( $(ls -l "$gl_file") )
    gl_orig="${gl_orig_a[-1]}"
}
for i in *; do 
    get_lnk "$i"
    echo "file: $gl_file"
    echo "links to: $gl_orig"
    echo
done

# output:

file: file-l
links to: ../file

file: file-l2
links to: ../file
```

This prints the name of the symlink and the name of the file it points to. This is actually the opposite of what I'm trying to do, but is reasonably useful (when all the links are in the same place).

Comment: I'm not trying to make a thread like those that ask for opinions, etc (and then get quickly closed for being unproductive). I'm more aiming for "how to do [thing] without getting too complicated"

Comment: [This will find the files that are hard linked or symlinked to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4535344/3776858)

Comment: While at it - what about multiple links? I mean, if you have  `link1 -> link2` and `link2 -> file`? I think that @Cyrus link will not find them all, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @cyrus hmm, didn't know find had an -L option. I only know about '-type l'. Excellent solution! I suggest you post this as a real answer

Comment: @Rmano interesting observation. Though if the -L version works on symlinks as well, you could feasibly make a loop to go thorough each result and recursively find all of their links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a file named `file1` in `~/tmp`, and let's say that you want to recursively remove all the symlinks to `file1` in `~/tmp`;

Using `find`:

```
find ~/tmp -lname ~/tmp/file1 -exec rm {} +
```

- `~/tmp`: specifies the path to the directory hierarchy in which to search;
- `-lname`: searches only for symlinks linking to `~/tmp/file1`;
- `-exec rm {} +`: removes all the results;

Sample output on a test directory hierarchy:

```
user@debian ~/tmp % tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   │   ├── 3
│   │   │   ├── link3-1 -> /home/user/tmp/file1
│   │   │   └── link3-2 -> /home/user/tmp/file2
│   │   ├── link2-1 -> /home/user/tmp/file1
│   │   └── link2-2 -> /home/user/tmp/file2
│   ├── link1-1 -> /home/user/tmp/file1
│   └── link1-2 -> /home/user/tmp/file2
├── file1
└── file2

3 directories, 8 files
user@debian ~/tmp % find . -lname ~/tmp/file1 -exec rm {} +
user@debian ~/tmp % tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   │   ├── 3
│   │   │   └── link3-2 -> /home/user/tmp/file2
│   │   └── link2-2 -> /home/user/tmp/file2
│   └── link1-2 -> /home/user/tmp/file2
├── file1
└── file2

3 directories, 5 files
```

Comment: Right on the mark. I personally avoid -exec because it's unintuitive as hell, and just wrap the find in a loop to make things simpler. However, would you care to explain the `{} +`? `-exec rm` is reasonable enough, and I suppose `{}` could be shorthand for "this", but the +?

Comment: @B1KMusic I prefer `-exec` for the simple reason that it won't break on edge cases such as filenames containing newlines, however reasonably enough that's, again, an edge case. Not at all, basically in the `-exec` switch you always reference a filename / a list of filenames using `{}`: if you choose to use `{}` followed by `\;`, `{}` will be replaced with a single filename and the command will run multiple times each time on a different filename; if you choose to use `{}` followed by `+`, `{}` will be replaced with the whole list of filenames and the command will run once for all the filenames

Comment: @B1KMusic I.e. `{}` followed by `+` will be considered as a list of arguments; mind that when using this method everything after `{}` until `+` is ignored, so sometimes this method won't fit the command you need to run; also using this method might result in the command using a list of filenames whose length exceedes the kernel's `ARG_MAX` threshold, and consequently in an error; if that's the case however you might just run `find ~/tmp -lname ~/tmp/file1 -exec rm {} \;` in place of `find ~/tmp -lname ~/tmp/file1 -exec rm {} +`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very thorough. Just out of curiosity, say I set `IFS=' '`, would this fix that newline edge case assuming none of the filenames have any spaces in them? What about simply surrounding `$file` with quotation marks?

Comment: @B1KMusic `IFS=' '` would make `bash` split fields on spaces, so no, also if you're talking about a `while read` loop `read` itself plays a role, and setting `$IFS` on its own is not useful; the situation is further complicated if you're talking about a `for` loop; I don't think there's a way to make it work with a `for` loop at all. I don't know which `$file` you're talking about, but assuming a `$file` reference in a `for` / `while` loop that should be quoted regardless, otherwise commands would split on whitespaces.

Comment: @B1KMusic  In the end if you want to use a `while read` loop, the only way is to set `find` to print NUL-terminated filenames (i.e. `find . -print0`) and `read` to split on NUL characters (and to not treat backslashes specially: `while read -d $'\0' -r` or `while read -d '' -r` will both split on NUL characters and not treat backslashes specially); for example `while read -d $'\0' -r; do [...]; done < <(find . -print0)` or `find . -print0 | while read -d $'\0' -r; do [...]; done`

Comment: @B1KMusic The above is the only way I'm aware of (and the one I usually use) to take care of *any* edge case; both newlines and backslashes, which are usually the problem, won't break anything using the above method

Comment: I was thinking something more like `IFS=$'\0'; files=($(<the read command>)); for file in $files; do <some_command> "$file"; done`. Either way, I appreciate the warning, and I'll try not to put newlines or backslashes in my filenames ;)